# asp.net mvc 5 parameter datatime ajax parameter always null in controller

Tags: asp.net, datetime, parameters, controller, null

I call my view from a controller with this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SalesReportViewModel salesReportView = new SalesReportViewModel {From = DateTime.Now, To = DateTime.Now};
    return View(salesReportView);
}
```

and in my view I have this Scrypt:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From, new { id = "fromEdit" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.To, new { id = "toEdit"})
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataToSend = {
            pFrom: $("#fromEdit").val(),
            pTo: $("#toEdit").val()
        };

        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": RootUrl + "SalesDetailsReport/GetSalesDetailReport",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":  dataToSend ,
                "dataType": "json"
            },
    });
</script>
```

the ajax call at this controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSalesDetailReport(DateTime? pFrom , DateTime? pTo)
    {
        if (pFrom != null)
        {
            List<SalesDetailsReportViewModel> salesDetailsReportViewModel =
                repository.ListDetailSalesReport((DateTime) pFrom, (DateTime) pTo);
            //Return the data as a jsonp result
            return Json(new {data = salesDetailsReportViewModel}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

My problem is that the parameter `(DateTime? pFrom , DateTime? pTo)` in the controller always receive null, can be for some conversion reading here:

```
    var dataToSend = {
        pFrom: $("#fromEdit").val(),
        pTo: $("#toEdit").val()
    };
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

replacing 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.From, new { htmlAttributes = new
by
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From, new { htmlAttributes = new

and works fine. Is like EditFor and javascrypt ar not good friends...

I don't know why but is working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the `ajax call` post a data type string but your controller is looking for a something like `DateTime? pFrom`.
try this in your Controller (language: c#):

```cs
pFrom= (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["From"])) ? DateTime.ParseExact(Request["From"].Trim(),"MM/dd/yyyy", null) : pFrom;

pTo= (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["To"])) ? DateTime.ParseExact(Request["To"].Trim(),"MM/dd/yyyy", null) : pTo;
```